# Adding JQuery in Wordpress page through plugin not working

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to add some Jquery and CSS code to my Wordpress page. I have tried numerous plugins like Advanced Custom Field, Insert Header and Footer, Scripts n Styles, Simple Custom CSS and JS, Simple JS Paste, etc. and followed each one's method to the T, but the Jquery script refuses to kick-in. (Not facing a problem with the CSS which works even when I include it in the Theme's custom CSS)

Where am I going wrong? COuld someone please help me with a better method to include the JQuery in the page?

Code:

```js
 
        jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
            var StatJSON = {
            "Opt1":  {
                "Name": "Mat",
                "Parameter1": "65",
                "Parameter2": "30"
            },
            "Opt2": {
                "Name": "Mik",
                "Parameter1": "62",
                "Parameter2": "40"
            },
            "Opt3": {
                "Name": "Mir",
                "Parameter1": "65",
                "Parameter2": "90"
            }
        };

        $('#btnSubmit').click(function(){ 
        var resultString = '';
        $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
        var this_input = $(this);
        if (this_input.is(':checked')){
        resultString += PrintHtml(StatJSON[$(this).val()]);
        }
        });
        $('#divResult').html(resultString);
        });
    });

    function PrintHtml(obj){
        var html='<div class="opt">';
        if (obj){
            $.each(obj, function(k,v){
                html += '<div>'+k+' : '+v+'</div>'; 
            });
        }
        html += '</div>';
        return html;
    }
```

```css
.opt{
             margin: 10px;
             padding: 10px;
             background: #eee;
             border: 1px solid #222;
         }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        </head>
     <style></style>   
    <body>
    Options:
    <input type="checkbox" name="Station" value="Opt1">Option1
    <input type="checkbox" name="Station" value="Opt2">Option2
    <input type="checkbox" name="Station" value="Opt3">Option3
    <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="submit" />
    <br /><br />
    <div id="divResult"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Any error displayed in console?

Comment: Open the developer's console by pressing Ctrl+Shift+I for chrome. And check for any erros in the console tab.

Comment: @TamilSelvanC The console shows the following: "JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1". What could be the issue???

Comment: @SagarBahadurTamang The console shows the following: "JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1".

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in you active themes functions.php  or in your plugin your script should be in footer

```
add_action('wp_footer','add_my_code');

function add_my_code(){

?>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
            var StatJSON = {
            "Opt1":  {
                "Name": "Mat",
                "Parameter1": "65",
                "Parameter2": "30"
            },
            "Opt2": {
                "Name": "Mik",
                "Parameter1": "62",
                "Parameter2": "40"
            },
            "Opt3": {
                "Name": "Mir",
                "Parameter1": "65",
                "Parameter2": "90"
            }
        };
        jQuery('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(e){
            jQuery(this).attr('checked',true);
        });

        jQuery('#btnSubmit').click(function(){ 

        var resultString = '';
        jQuery('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(a) {
        var this_input = jQuery(this);
        if (this_input.is(':checked')){
        resultString += PrintHtml(StatJSON[jQuery(this).val()]);
        }
        });
        jQuery('#divResult').html(resultString);
        });
    });

    function PrintHtml(obj){
        var html='<div class="opt">';
        if (obj){
            jQuery.each(obj, function(k,v){
                html += '<div>'+k+' : '+v+'</div>'; 
            });
        }
        html += '</div>';
        return html;
    }
</script>
<style>
.opt{
             margin: 10px;
             padding: 10px;
             background: #eee;
             border: 1px solid #222;
         }
</style>
<?php

}
```

Comment: Hi @RajdeepTayde Thanks! I tried to add this to the functions.php file but it messed the site, so I had to restore the file. Is there a way I can do it without editing the function.php file? I tried header and footer plugins but they don't seem to work. Thanks again!

Comment: you have to debug why it is messing the site maybe you need this code to be run on only one page so you can add is_page function so that this script and style loads only on the page you require

Comment: I have also changed the above code and it does not break the page add it at the end of functions.php

Comment: Hi @RajdeepTayde Thanks!! This worked as you said!! :) Though I'm not sure why it didn't work when I used the same code in a seperate .js file and called it with the following code in function.php. Any thoughts on why it didn't work??? Code: `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
  'compare15Mar19',
  get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/compare15Mar19.js',
  array('jquery')
 );  
}`

Comment: Would also be a great, great help if you could have a look at the JQuery code above. It's currently giving me separate tables for each selected input. But the keys (row heading) are the same, I actually require each selection to appear to the right of the previous selection in a single table. Basically I need to build a simple comparison table to compare each option across parameters. Thanks again for all the help!!!!! :)